# youtube iframe disable fast forward but not rewind button react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

Hello im trying to display youtube videos on my react native app, i am using react-native-youtube-iframe library and my youtube player code is in below

```
<YoutubePlayer
  height={300}
  play={true}
  videoId={this.props.route.params.data.video.url}
  onChangeState={(event) => console.log(event)}
  initialPlayerParams={{'controls': false}}
 />
```

i am disabling all controls using initialPlayerParams but i just want to prevent user from skipping video and user will have to wait until end, i will get ending event with onChangeState.
Problem is i want user to be able to rewind when needed, is it possible to do it using youtube API or do i have to write my own functions connected to onChangeState